# Use of test/resource files to compare unit test output = code smell?

Tags: unit-testing, testing

Is it a code smell to use a generated file, like a spreadsheet or XML file, as a source for comparison in Unit tests?

Say that we had to write a lot of classes that produce various XML files for processing later. The unit tests would be a large number of repetitive assertions that `foo.getExpectedValue() = expectedValue`. Instead of doing this, the developer chooses to use the code they are supposed to be testing to generate the XML, then copy that into test/resources for all future tests load into memory as an object and to run their assertions against. Is this a code smell?

Answer (score 2):

There are two practices in what you describe that classify as test smells.

First, you write that the classes that are to be tested are used to create the XML files that are later used to judge the correctness.  This way you can find out if there are changes in the classes, but you can not figure out if the results were correct in the first place.

To avoid any misunderstandings: The smell is not that generated files are used, but that the files are generated with the code under test.  The only way how such an approach might make sense would be if the results of the initial run were subject to thorough review.  But, these reviews would have to be repeated again whenever the files are re-generated later.

Secondly, using complete XML files for comparison (generated or not) is another test small.  The reason is, that these tests are not very focused.  Any change to the XML generation will lead to a failing test.  That may seem like a good thing, but it even applies to all kinds of intended changes, for example to changes in the indentation.  Thus, you only have test that tell you "something changed", but not "something failed".

To have tests that tell you "something failed" you need more specific tests.  For example, tests that only look at a certain portion of the generated XML.  Some tests would look at the XML structure, others at the data content.  You can even have tests to check the indentation.  But, how?  You could, for example, use regular expressions to see if some interesting portion of a generated XML string looks the way you expected.

Once you have more focused tests, then the rest results in case of intended modifications to your code will look different: When your changes are successfull, only a few test cases of many will fail, and this will be the ones that have tested against the part of the behaviour that you intentionally have changed.  All other tests will still work OK and show you that your change did not break something unexpectedly.  If in contrast your change was incorrect, then some more/other tests than the expected ones will show you that the change had unexpected effects.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, I wouldn't do that. This is breaking principles of a good test. Mainly, a good test test should be;

- Independent - should not rely on other tests. If subsequent tests have to wait for a file generated by the first test,tests are not independent.
- Repeatable - these tests introduce the flakiness due to the file/in-memory dependency. Therefore, they may not be repeatable consistently.

Perhaps, you could take a step back and see whether you need to unit test every generated XML. If these file generation follow the same code execution path with (no logical difference), I wouldn't write unit test per each case. If these XML generation is business operation related, I would consider having acceptance tests.

Answer (score 0):

If the files are *small*, you can use string reader and writer. In general one is supposed to avoid doing i/o in *unit* tests. However,I see nothing wrong with using files in some non-unit tests.